# .php открывает как текст

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста я запустил сайт и после этого браузер не читает .php файлы а читает только .html в чём проблема и как мне его исправить

Comment: какой сервер?..

Comment: Возможно вы не установили PHP к своему веб-серверу, загуглите инфу типа: 'Установка PHP Nginx/Apache2'

Answer (score 0):

1 - напишите в поддержку сервера, пускай настроят вам работу php и конфигурацию nginx/apache

2 - изучите всю информацию по ссылке на будущее) https://www.php.net/manual/ru/getting-started.php